# Deleting in linked lists?

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student{
char name[25];
double gpa;
struct student *next;
};

struct student *list_head;

struct student *create_new_student(char nm[], double gpa) 
{
         struct student *st;
         printf("\tcreating node\t");
         printf("\nName=%s \t Gpa= %.2f\n", nm, gpa);

         st = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof (struct student ));
         strcpy(st->name, nm);
         st->gpa = gpa;
         st->next = NULL;
         return st;
}

void printstudent(struct student *st) 
{
         printf("\nName %s,GPA %f\n", st->name, st->gpa);
}

void insert_first_list(struct student *new_node) 
{
         printf("\nInserting node: ");
         printstudent(new_node);
         new_node->next = list_head;
         list_head = new_node;
}

struct student *delete_first_node() 
{
         struct student *deleted_node;
         printf("\nDeleting node: ");
         printstudent(deleted_node);
         list_head = list_head->next;
         return deleted_node;
}

void printlist(struct student *st)
{
         printf("\nPrinting list: ");
         while(st != NULL) {
             printstudent(st);
             st = st->next;
         }
}

int main() 
{
         struct student *other;
         list_head = create_new_student("Adil", 3.1);
         other = create_new_student("Fatima", 3.8);
         insert_first_list(other);
         printlist(list_head);
         other = delete_first_node();
         printlist(list_head);
         return 0;
}
```

When I run it, there are no errors or warnings. However, it stops at the delete part.The message says the program has stopped working.

Can you please help me find the problem?

Comment: The message means the program has crashed. Take the help of debugger to sort out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `delete_first_node` the node `deleted_node` is not initialized and passed to function `printstudent` which try to access its member, results in **undefined behavior**.
The function should be

```
struct student *delete_first_node(){
    struct student *deleted_node = list_head;
    printf("\nDeleting node: ");
    if(deleted_node != NULL)
    {
        printstudent(deleted_node);
        list_head= list_head->next;
        free(deleted_node);
    }
    else
       printf("List is emty\n");

    return list_head;
}
```

Comment: @user3096716; see, you need to free the deleted node which I forgot to mention. See the new edit.